# I'm trying to display a certain part of an Iframe that I target with its class name

Tags: javascript, html

**I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to target a specific class name in an Iframe from another website, so I'm able to only show the current price of BTC. I don't know if this is possible though, or if there is even a way I can get the .value of the the target class somehow. Hope someone can help, I appreciate it.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div>
     <iframe id="price" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>

<script>

const price = document.getElementById("price");
price.style.width = "400px";
price.style.height = "400px";
price.src = "https://blockfolio.com/coin/BTC";
price.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("PriceFlasher__PriceFlasherWrapper-sc-14r4saj-0 gOyVu");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry If I wasnt clear with my problem. I just want the Iframe to display the price of BTC. I tried targeting it with its class name but it still shows the whole page.

Comment: What do you mean by "it still shows the whole page"? Do you only want it to display the targeted class?

Comment: Yes, only the targeted class that I specified in the last piece of my js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely not possible, as iframes have security policies preventing you from accessing the document from another domain.  In addition, it's probably a bad idea - the fact that the class name ends in `sc-14r4saj-0 gOyVu` means it's most likely bundled and when they deploy a new version, the class names will change (breaking your app).  Not sure if blockfolio has an API, but that is probably what you want to do, something like:

Probably a much better solution would be:

```js
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});
const priceEl = document.getElementById('price');
let priceFloat;
const update = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
    const json = await resp.json();
    if (priceFloat !== json.bpi.USD.rate_float) {
        const color = priceFloat && priceFloat < json.bpi.USD.rate_float ? 'red' : 'green';
        priceFloat = json.bpi.USD.rate_float;
        const money = formatter.format(json.bpi.USD.rate_float);
        price.innerHTML = money;
        price.style.color = color;
        setTimeout(() => price.style.color = null, 500);
    }
}
update();
setInterval(update, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="price"></div>
```